# Google authorization access API via browser

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-java-client

I have a problem with my Google API.
I would like to avoid going through a browser to retrieve my access authorization.
I would like to retrieve the code directly into a variable.
This is the kind of URL that I sent :

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=2131233123321332&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly&redirect_uri=https://tito.com

Comment: Show us what you have tried already...

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=22fdgdfg40-1gmgdfggdps0hfol.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://tito.com/&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly");
HttpResponse responses = client.execute(httpget);

HttpParams param = responses.getParams();

responses.getParams().getParameter("code");
System.out.println(responses.getParams().getParameter("code"));
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responses.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```